AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
Главный файл / Main file
import os
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
from ds1 import TOKEN

intents=disnake.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=intents, test_guilds=[1268858555616854106])
intents.members = True

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Бот {bot.user} готов к работе")

@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    bot.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    bot.reload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")

for filename in os.listdir("A:/test/discord/course1/cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

bot.run(TOKEN)

Cog файл / file
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands

class Members(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        guild = self.bot.get_guild(1268873156441931806)
        role = disnake.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=1268865812350111775)
        embed = disnake.Embed(title="Title", description=f"Description {member.mention}", color=0x27152f)
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await guild.send(embed=embed)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Members(bot))

Ошибка / Error
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:\Programms\Python\Lib\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 703, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "a:\test\discord\course1\cogs\member.py", line 14, in on_member_join
    await guild.send(embed=embed)
          ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'


Метод get_guild() возвращает None, если не находит guild по id. Либо перепроверьте Ваш id, либо не хардкодьте значение id (а передавайте через переменные) + настройте обработку случая, когда guild is None
